# Stretch the image in the first slide Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]
I have this slick slider and i want to Stretch the image in the first current active slide

i want do this https://prnt.sc/slrcny

for example here [example working slider](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/417005246752014274/feedback/?invite_code=7c3e82287b164a05b0155fc669691205&sender_id=417005384155291210) you want to see this example. First current active slide is 
Stretch. How i can do it in the slick slider ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-nav div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}

.slider-for {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin
}

.slider-wrap {
  positon: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.slick-arrow:before {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="slider-wrap">


  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"> </img>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x51"> </img>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x52"> </img>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x53"> </img>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x54"> </img>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: Please provide more details about the end result you want to achieve ... you want something like [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/121808364907642181/) where a big image at the top and slide below it ???

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/r48y9jvq/

Comment: @HusseinAkar i want this https://prnt.sc/slrumq

Comment: @M.AShahbazi  yes , i  want this, but how i understand i will be needed change image , because i have one image little and one image big but i test it now and concluded that quality is lost

Comment: Your images should be same size, you can crop them on the server side. since we are using `background-size: cover` here then it will make the image to stretched and fit the whole `<div class="slide-photo"></div>`

Comment: To test quickly without worrying about images quality and size use this as source: 
[http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x400](http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x400) the 200x400 are dynamic you could replace them with any width & height you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working snippet for what you want to achieve, in this case the images sizes are `400x600` but since we are using the `background-size: cover` property the image will be covered in the whole `<div class="slide-photo"></div>`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        centerMode: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
    });
});
```

```css
.slider-nav {
  height: 400px;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide {
  margin: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide .slide-photo {
  -webkit-transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50%;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide .slide-photo::after, .slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide .slide-photo::before {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #ffbf00;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1);
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide .slide-photo:after {
  right: 50%;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide .slide-photo:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide.slick-current .slide-photo {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide.slick-current .slide-photo:before, .slider-nav .slick-list .slick-slide.slick-current .slide-photo:after {
  width: 50%;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div>
        <div class="slide-photo" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/one/400/600);"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-photo" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/fdsgds/400/600);"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-photo" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/gwegwe/400/600);"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but there, as I understand it, on a small screen, not the whole picture is visible. I add background-size: cover but i's not work

Comment: You can define your responsive breakpoints on Slick and make your own adjustments for that.

Comment: I want to big size and small size i can see the whole picture

Comment: What you really asking for is impossible to achieve since your active state image is more like a rectangle and your inactive state is a square. You can't make the image to fit in a square and rectangle at the same time. Maybe you can try `background-size: contain` for the inactive state and `background-size: cover` for the active state? Try that and let me know if that's working for you.